# Need help on php-fpm error 503

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a issue for a few days now ! I'm using Symfony 3 + EasyAdmin on a Vagrant + Puphpet (PHP-FPM and Apache).

I added a new entity and tried to add some data from the admin. But, for some reason I can't quite understand when try to insert the data I get a 503 error from Apache (meaning it's not stylized as Symfony does). When I try to see in Apache Log I find this :

```
   [Fri Mar 11 13:45:05.240107 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16535:tid 140223207917312] [client 192.168.56.1:34080] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header, referer: http://shop-generator.dev/app_dev.php/admin/?action=new&entity=Foe&menuIndex=11&page=1&referer=%252Fapp_dev.php%252Fadmin%252F%253Faction%253Dlist%2526entity%253DFoe%2526menuIndex%253D11%2526submenuIndex%253D0%2526sortField%253Did%2526sortDirection%253DDESC%2526page%253D1&sortDirection=DESC&sortField=id&submenuIndex=0
[Fri Mar 11 13:45:05.249001 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16535:tid 140223207917312] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.56.1:34080] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: http://shop-generator.dev/app_dev.php/admin/?action=new&entity=Foe&menuIndex=11&page=1&referer=%252Fapp_dev.php%252Fadmin%252F%253Faction%253Dlist%2526entity%253DFoe%2526menuIndex%253D11%2526submenuIndex%253D0%2526sortField%253Did%2526sortDirection%253DDESC%2526page%253D1&sortDirection=DESC&sortField=id&submenuIndex=0
```

And I tried to get a backtrace with the core but it has proven very complicated.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I finally tried by putting some data into the database manually and everything works ... except the creation ... I really don't get why ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a 503 is typically `service unavailable`, meaning apache cant communicate with the `php-fpm` process manager. Try to terminate `php-fpm` and restart it. On my box :

```
sh-3.2# killall php-fpm
sh-3.2# php-fpm
```

If it restarts normally and your app works, try to figure out why you ran out or worker processes. It happens to me frequently with PhpStorm during an intense debugging session, when i kill the debug. PhpStorm clings to the connexion. I have to terminate by hand all the debug processes (or restart PhpStorm if it is faster than 'click-are u sure-yes`...`click-are u sure-yes` ... etc)

If `php-fpm` restarts normally but your problem remains, there is probably a configuration change you are unaware of that took place (like the port number dedicated to `php-fpm`).

Also, another process could be grabbing the configured port. If another app has the `php-fpm` port, you should see :

```
sh-3.2# php-fpm
[11-Mar-2016 08:49:19.765233] ERROR: pid 888, fpm_sockets_new_listening_socket(), line 191: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:8001': Address already in use (48)
[11-Mar-2016 08:49:19.765337] ERROR: pid 888, fpm_init(), line 72: FPM initialization failed
sh-3.2#
```

If that happens, the hunt is on to figure out which process is occupying the port allocated to `php-fpm` in your configuration files.

edit : the specific error you posted from apache occurs (typically) on a timeout, eg the fpm process took too long to complete the http request. You could have a debug process stuck on a breakpoint, or a long processing process being serviced, or some other obscure cause : I have had 'too many files open', an xdebug log file in the multi Gb size, others.

Comment: PHP-FPM runs better with Nginx right ? Maybe that's why ? I thought maybe it was because of the size of the referer too but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved a [503 similar problem](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1671) with a `vagrant reload --provision` command.

Hope that it'll help you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12088647)

Comment: Hi Sergiu, I'm completely agree with you, that's why I have included the command (vagrant reload --provision) which has resolved my problem